# Retrieve user pool ID using only a client ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have a use case requiring multiple user pools in Cognito.  Each pool has a client, which enables the client credentials flow.

During the client credentials flow, the user of the API sends the client ID and client secret, and we then call a user pool specific endpoint to generate an access token.  What I'd like to do is retrieve the user pool ID using **only** the client ID given in the request, and ideally retrieve it directly from AWS.  Is this possible?

I realize we can likely use a combination of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUserPools-property) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUserPoolClients-property), where you can list all the user pools and then list all the clients belonging to those.  I know we'd also be able to store the association on our end in a DB.  However, it would be much better to just be able to make an SDK call to retrieve the pool ID, saving us the custom code and DB management.

Does anybody know if it's possible to do a direct lookup of the user pool ID using the client ID, whether it's in the SDK (Nodejs), their API, or using some unofficial methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly sure there is no cognito-idp call you can use for this, I have been working in the cognito idp api a fair amount recently and also wanted this functionality.

As an alternative you could add a `tag` to the user pool resource for each client, with the key being the client id and the value being the user pool id. Then make a call to `get-tag-values` for that tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  That's about the same conclusion I've come to, but I hadn't thought of using tags for this.  AFAICS, that fits our use case perfectly.  Thanks!